# Reload middleman when data/ file change

Tags: ruby, middleman

How do I force middleman to reload when I edit the data file?

For example. This is my app:

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── config.rb
├── data
│   └── products.yml
└── source
    ├── ...
```

When I edit `data/products.yml` the data does not appear on the site *until* I manually restart the server with `bundle exec middleman`.

Comment: if you add "puts config[:file_watcher_ignore]" to your config.rb, what does it print when you start middleman? Is data/ in one of those?

Comment: ```== The Middleman is loading
(?-mix:^bin\/)
(?-mix:^\.bundle\/)
(?-mix:^vendor\/)
(?-mix:^\.sass-cache\/)
(?-mix:^\.git\/)
(?-mix:^\.gitignore$)
(?-mix:\.DS_Store)
(?-mix:^\.rbenv-.*$)
(?-mix:^Gemfile$)
(?-mix:^Gemfile\.lock$)
(?-mix:~$)
(?-mix:(^|\/)\.?#)
(?-mix:^tmp\/)```

Comment: I experience the same, both version 3.1.5 and 3.1.6. Although middleman is correctly noticing the changed data files: `Changed! data/ ...`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I figured it out and posted the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you manually add `data` to the reload paths

```
middleman server --reload-paths data/
```

https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/726

Comment: I am running the command above. I am getting an error - Unknown switches '--reload-paths' @luk3thomas